# What do you call it when a spectator distracts a player.

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns

Like when a member of the audience yells at a player so he misses his shot.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. When asking for a word or phrase, we ask that you provide an example sentence for how it will be used. Some additional background would be helpful as well— are you looking for terminology, or jargon from sports journalism? Does it make a difference if the distraction is expected as part of the game (as with basketball free throws) or frowned upon (as with golf or tennis)? Have you tried any research, like finding descriptions of famous incidents? I encourage you to take the [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 5):

**Heckle** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heckle)

> *verb* to interrupt (someone, such as a speaker or performer) by shouting annoying or rude comments or questions.

When someone from the audience interrupts the performer, it's called **heckling**. Such a person is called a **heckler**. I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heckler) that it's commonly used in sports, too.

> The sport of cricket is particularly notorious for heckling between the teams themselves, which is known as [sledging](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sledging_(cricket)).