# Verb for discouraging or laughing at someone especially celebrity in public

Tags: single-word-requests

I used to know a word that had a specific meaning and its meaning was something along the lines of *to discourage someone from presenting/ performing something in public or laughing at someone and making them feel ashamed while they are performing in public.*
It was used for celebrity who perform in public like a singer who sings and you __ him.

I searched the synonyms of "discourage" and "laugh at" but I can't seem to find the word I am looking for.

An example sentence is:

> Justin Beiber was singer in public concert and people ____ed him so he left the concert".

I had seen this word in a video as I remember but I have forgotten the name of what I was watching. In that video, a person is trying to sing in public and people laugh at him and discourage him and he then leaves that place as he is disappointed by the reaction of the public and then sits on a bench far away from people. The host of the video was describing that action and used a word (verb) for that I am trying to remember that verb but I can't seem to find it anywhere. It's 3rd day now since I have  been searching for different words.
Please help me find that word.

P.S I hope I provided enough information about the word I am searching, if it is inappropriate here, please close the question.

Comment: Probably you want ***mocked***.

Comment: **Deride** is another possibility.

Comment: Similar questions: [What’s a good synonym for when a sports player get mockingly booed by the crowd?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/523796/365490) ///// [What do you call it when a spectator distracts a player.](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/316777/365490).

Comment: *jeered, mocked, heckled, taunted, booed, derided, scoffed at, ridiculed,...* There are many *possible* words, but no single "unambiguously correct" answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say he was **heckled**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/heckle) has

> **heckle**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> **1** Interrupt (a public speaker) with derisive or aggressive comments or abuse.
> *he was booed and heckled when he tried to address the demonstrators*

So the sentence would be

> Justin Beiber was [a] singer in [a] public concert and people heckled him so he left the concert